# WIFI SSID is not visible in available connections

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wireless-access-point

Well, this was working fine before I went up North and accidently clicked on the forget network option. When I got home, I placed the laptop next to router and the SSID is not broadcasting. I see my neighbor's SSIDs and I see my printer just fine. I tried adding it in the Manage WIFI Connections and it's been added but there is no way to actually connect to this.

I enabled the hotspot on my phone, which uses the desired SSID and was able to successfully connect using that. I have tried resetting my network, I reset the laptop back to factory and I even removed the network adapter in Device Manager and then scanned and re-added it but to no avail.

This is plain strange. All my other devices see this connection, fine, however, my laptop doesn't.

I see a "Hidden" connection and tried connecting that by providing the SSID and passphrase but that doesn't work.

I checked my router software and the laptop isn't being backlisted. When I connect using a cable, I can see my device as "wired" on the admin panel for listed devices in the router admin UI.

Not sure if any one else has any ideas or has experienced this before.

Just to reiterate, I see several SSIDs listed, so I know the adapter is working.

Thanks,
Branden